# Confusion with data modeling in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, nosql

I'm a bit new to Cassandra and got stuck with data modeling. Let's say, we have clients and customers, relation between them are regulated by dozens of rules (that could lives for different periods of time, number of rules could vary in time, new rules could be added, old could be removed and so on; basically, I do not have any control over them) and some metric associated with each rule.

I need to support following:

- querying a table for particular combination of a client, customer and rule between given time interval
- ability to easily truncate data that is old enough

For now, I came up with 2 possible solutions, but, unfortunately they don't satisfy both conditions at the same time.

1.) This options works fine for data selection, but it's impossible to delete old data with such structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_cluster.data_per_rule (
        client text,
        customer text,
        rule text,
        time timestamp,
        count counter,
        PRIMARY KEY((client, customer), rule, time)
    )
```

Associated `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT time, count FROM data_per_rule WHERE
      client = 'client-1' AND
      customer = 'customer-1' AND
      rule = 'rule-1' AND
      time >= 1471464960000 time < 1471551360000
```

2.) And this case suits deletion of out-of-date data, but it's too complicated to query such table for the data for the last hour, for example.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_cluster.data_per_rule (
        day date
        client text,
        customer text,
        rule text,
        moment time,
        count counter,
        PRIMARY KEY((day), client, customer, rule, moment)
    )
```

Pretty simple deletion:

```
DELETE FROM data_per_rule WHERE day = '2016-08-18'
```

My question is could I model the table to support both requirements without storing some additional information (rule ids, for example)?

Comment: If you are using cassandra 3.x you can try using materialized views ?

Comment: @GuillaumeS, could you, please, clarify how it could help?

Comment: Of course, you can create your 2) table to delete data per day and create a materialized view based on 2) with a primary key (client, customer), rule, time, day for example. With this structure, if you delete a recored in table 2), cassandra will automatically delete associated recoed in your second table. In other word : insert, update and delete in table 2) and SELECT in view.

Comment: @GuillaumeS, I see, what you're talking about, but materialized view is not supported on top of counter tables.